Angular modules are not taking global styles and scss variables
In my angular app i have src/styles.scss
@import "./styles/fonts";
@import "./styles/variables.scss";

and in src/styls/variables.scss
$color-brand-darker: #2d323e;
$color-brand-dark: #0e2c6c;

and i have modules that are being loaded lazily. and this is how i am mentioning styles for a component in a module
@Component({
    selector: 'my-card',
    templateUrl: './my-card.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-card.component.scss'],

and in angular.json
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "gothia": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "projectType": "application",
            "prefix": "app",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "style": "scss"
                }
            },
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/web.config",
                            "src/manifest.json"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.scss",
                            "node_modules/intro.js/introjs.css",
                            "node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/intro.js/intro.js"
                        ]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "development": {
                            "buildOptimizer": false,
                            "optimization": false,
                            "vendorChunk": true,
                            "sourceMap": true,
                            "namedChunks": true
                        },
                        "production" : {}

in the options i have mentioned the styles as well but on build using this comamnd
"build": "ng build --configuration production",

showing me the error
./src/app/pages/my-view/components/my-card/my-card.component.scss?ngResource - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Undefined variable.
   ╷
30 │         border-left: 5px solid $color-brand-darker;
   │                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

am i missing something?
my styles.scss is mentioned in angular.json and making this as global styles!!
so every module shuld have access to access these variables without importing in each component level scss for modules
package json versions
"sass-loader": "13.3.2",
"devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "16.2.14",
        "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^16.0.1",

"@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "16.0.1",
        "@angular/animations": "16.0.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "16.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "16.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "16.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "16.0.0",


I dont think you can do that, global variables have to be wrapped in root {}
As far as i know this is the only way relative close
variables.scss
$colors: (
  brand-darker: #2d323e,
  brand-dark: #0e2c6c,
);

:root {
  @each $name, $color in $colors {
    --color-#{$name}: #{$color};
  }
}

styles.scss
@import './styles/variables';

NOTE: you can simplyfy import if you add below configuation under architect>build>options in angular.json
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
     "src/styles"
  ]
}

you will be able to import by typing @import 'variables';
Now use variable wherever it is with
color: var(--color-brand-darker);


so this is only for scss variables?  and for @mixin? otherwise normal scss class rules will be shared as it?

@SunilGarg you can't even do this when it comes to mixins. There is no way to provide global access to mixins, each file that uses them, has to import mixin file

@SunilGarg yes. The only thing you can globally apply is plain css/scss. Everything that comes with inner context like, mixins, functions, etc... can't be provided globally

so files for mixin i need to import in every scss file ?

Strictly speaking yes, you have to import them in every scss file, because sass itself does not allow it otherwise.  But there can be external solution to your problem, for example webpack,  using webpack you will be able to globalize both variables and mixins or whatever you want. Although behind the scene webpack will do the same import in all the files, just like you would have done.

now i am facing issues for loading these css variables `File was processed with these loaders:

./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js
./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.


:root {
|   --color-brand-darker: #2d323e;`

i added mentioned entry in angular.json as well

It is year 2024 and I guess it would be easier to use css variables instead of scss ones today:
 // src/styls/variables.scss
html {
  --color-brand-darker: #2d323e;
  --color-brand-dark: #0e2c6c;
}
// my-card.component.scss

border-left: 5px solid var(--color-brand-darker);

all modern browsers today support css variables. scss ones should be used only for libraries that depend on something scss specific or in some cases where you need to perform some maths on css values such as mixing colors or calculating angles/coordinates. support for different calculations is also coming but not everything is supported by all browsers yet.

yes, css variables can be used, but it should work , scss varaibles, the way i am using

and its not about only variables, i have other shared mixins as well

then it seems you have to import your file with variables into the every file where variables(mixins) are used

but ideally it should work without import due to global rules?

it is resolved by scss compiler. these variables don't exist in runtime

@Andrei CSS variables are not always a drop-in replacement for SCSS variables, they each serve their purpose. SCSS variables are meant to be compiled on the server and do not need to end up being served to the client.

Use variable.scss instead of import in style.scss
@use 'variables' as global;

Add variable.scss path to your angular.json file, Inside of styles block (in build config and not test config block), For styles like thems color add define colors like this: (:root{--app-primary-color: #red})
"styles": [
          "src/styles/variables.scss",
          "src/styles/styles.scss",
          ...
        ],

Inside of your my-card.component.scss use variables:
@use 'variables' as global;

.my-class {
    border-left: 5px solid global.$color-brand-darker;
    color: --app-primary-color;  // <---- for thems
}


i used first approach  like @use "styles/variables" as global;  and it did not work, or we need to mention in angular.json as well?

Add it to angular.json file and re-run the app

i tried but did not work

Check your path spell, you write src/styls/variables.scss that seems styls is not currect. also check the file name inside of angular.json. add your new angular.json file in your post
